# How do I roleplay Ziraj The Hunter?

Tags: forgotten-realms, roleplaying

Stipulated that the question in the title is an opinion so that's not the question I'm asking.

Background:  We are playing Waterdeep Dragonheist and, very temporarily, we are playing the Doom Raiders for.... reasons.  I've been assigned Ziraj The Hunter.

I'm trying to find some background information to better help me roleplay him, but it's very sparse.

This:  https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Ziraj

Tells me only that he's "taciturn" which is of no great help.

Is there some better resource that I can use to more effectively roleplay him?

Comment: Fortunately, if you play him really "taciturn" you don't really need to know anything about him. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Waterdeep: Dragon Heist has this to say about Ziraj:

> ...He's the strong, silent type.
>
>  The City Watch has received reports of a figure who haunts the rooftops of Waterdeep - a hulking shadow that glares from its perch, rains down death in the form of long black arrows, and slinks off without so much as a whisper. Where he comes from - if he even has a home - remains a mystery, as does the question of where he might show up next.

Outside of this particular adventure, he's not really mentioned anywhere. If you need any additional information, you'll probably have to talk to your DM. My players never met him, but personally I always saw Ziraj as the enforcer of the Doom Raiders.

Comment: Both were good answers, but I'm going with this one as it has the most "actionable" information.  At the end of the day the answer is more:  There's no information about him because he likes it that way.

Answer (score 4):

The Wiki you linked claims:

> Appearances
>
> - Adventures
>
>   - Waterdeep: Dragon Heist
> - Board Games
>
>   - Dungeons & Dragons Dice Masters: The Zhentarim

As far as my experience goes, Forgotten Realms Wiki is usually good in that matter, and my Google-fu did not reveal any other appearances either. Last but not least, all search results on D&D Beyond (https://www.dndbeyond.com/search?q=ziraj ) leads to Waterdeep: Dragon Heist content.

Sorry to say, but if adventure book doesn't give you the information you need, you have to consult your DM and fill the gaps with your own creativity.